# how to add title(Application name) in activity using tabhost

Tags: android, tabpanel

I have the app in which tab panel are at the bottom of the layout. 
Now I want to add actionbar with title and background color in the activity,but it always returns an error. I searched google but have found nothing. How can I add action bar in my application. please suggest me something.

**tabhostActivity**

```
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTabs() ;
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("Direction", R.drawable.tab_home, ArrowsActivity.class);
        addTab("About", R.drawable.tab_search, ImageActivity.class);

        addTab("Link", R.drawable.link, Link.class);
        //addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_search, OptionsActivity.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        //TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.niftem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/app_theme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TabSample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ImageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="ArrowsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="Link" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDNER8Dls96Gdkjf1yvhQAcF-4vul3Qr0I" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

**style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, TabSample!</string>
    <string name="app_name">NIFTEM</string>
    <string-array name="Spinner_Content">
        <item>One</item>
        <item>Two</item>
        <item>Three</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**dimension.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="corner_radius">8dp</dimen> 
    <dimen name="tab_space_top">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tab_space">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tab_space_plus1">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tab_space_bottom_line">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tab_space_unselected_top">6sp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider not using TabHost and using ActionbarActivity instead. It will set the tabs at the top, just below the action bar but with a litle mod I think you could set them at the bottom. Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @  masmic_87 why can't i add application title on the top with tabhost..,by default all application have title bar above on every application

Comment: If you just want to define an app title, it shouldn't be a problem. Post your manifest just to see if you are declaring right the label and also to see which theme you are using. Also take in account that defining app's name at the top is not the same as using an actionBar.

Comment: @  masmic_87 i post my manifest.

Comment: Which is your `app_name` and your `app_theme`? Maybe you have defined a custom style wich hides the app title?

Comment: @ masmic_87 thank you so much..,you are right,problem was in style.xml.,tnx

Comment: I think you have written wrong, what you've posted as `style.xml` is `string.xml`, and you forgot to post `style.xml`. I don't need dimension.xml

Comment: @ masmic_87 yes mistakenly i post string.xml..,but problem was in style.xml,declared app theme as parent.noactionbar.
Thank you

Comment: Ok, haven't seen the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem clearly.
In tab activities you can get action bar with

```
TabSample tabSample = (TabSample)getParent();
ActionBar actionBar = tabSample.getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Hello World");
```

I hope this will help you.

Edit: I recommend you to use fragments for tab pattern instead of using tab host. You can use this library for beginning and have good tabs.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip